# Text to Pascal Case using jquery and toLowerCase

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. But what I am trying to do is take UPPERCASE text (delivered from a database) and make it Pascal case. I am failing on the JQuery side of this. Do I need to review Lynda.com again? Thank you.

```
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#contextName").toLowerCase());
});
</script>

<style>
  #contextName {text-transform: capitalize;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="contextName">THIS IS UpPER CASE</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problems in many directions.

First off, there is no jQuery method `.toLowerCase()` so this is an error:

```
$("#contextName").toLowerCase()
```

Then, you have an extra closing paren in this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#contextName").toLowerCase());
});
```

Then, you aren't assigning the results of the `toLowerCase()` to anything so even if that method existed, it wouldn't do anything.

Then, you have a conflicting `text-transform` style which won't actually change the text, but may change how it displays.

Perhaps what you want is something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#contextName").text($("#contextName").text().toLowerCase());
});
```

Working demo without the text-transform: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KJQX5/

Working demo with the text-transform: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KBwWv/

---

And, you absolutely should learn how to look in your browser's error console so you can see any script errors you have in your page.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$("#contextName").text().toLowerCase()
```

to retrieve the value in lower case
or

```
$("#contextName").text($("#contextName").text().toLowerCase());
```

to set the content of the field to lower case

Comment: `.val()` is used on form elements, not `<p>` objects.